# Finance Yahoo Currencies API

Tags: currency, yql

Previously we are using https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json to get all the currencies exchange rate for our application. However, realized that currently this link doesn't work anymore. What should we use now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use YahooFinancials (Python Module) to get currency data from YahooFinanace:

```
$ pip install yahoofinancials
```

https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

currencies = ['EURUSD=X', 'JPY=X', 'GBPUSD=X']
yahoo_financials_currencies = YahooFinancials(currencies)
print(yahoo_financials_currencies.get_historical_price_data("2018-08-01", "2018-08-10", "daily"))
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "JPY=X": {
        "eventsData": {}, 
        "firstTradeDate": {
            "date": 846633600, 
            "formatted_date": "1996-10-30"
        }, 
        "currency": "JPY", 
        "prices": [
            {
                "high": 112.13700103759766, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-07-31", 
                "low": 111.69999694824219, 
                "adjclose": 111.80799865722656, 
                "date": 1533078000, 
                "close": 111.80799865722656, 
                "open": 111.79499816894531
            }, 
            {
                "high": 111.7239990234375, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-01", 
                "low": 111.33000183105469, 
                "adjclose": 111.62000274658203, 
                "date": 1533164400, 
                "close": 111.62000274658203, 
                "open": 111.63700103759766
            }, 
            {
                "high": 111.78299713134766, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-02", 
                "low": 111.0999984741211, 
                "adjclose": 111.69000244140625, 
                "date": 1533250800, 
                "close": 111.69000244140625, 
                "open": 111.6989974975586
            }, 
            {
                "high": 111.52200317382812, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-05", 
                "low": 111.16699981689453, 
                "adjclose": 111.23400115966797, 
                "date": 1533510000, 
                "close": 111.23400115966797, 
                "open": 111.21700286865234
            }, 
            {
                "high": 111.36399841308594, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-06", 
                "low": 110.9990005493164, 
                "adjclose": 111.33999633789062, 
                "date": 1533596400, 
                "close": 111.33999633789062, 
                "open": 111.3280029296875
            }, 
            {
                "high": 111.41999816894531, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-07", 
                "low": 110.83999633789062, 
                "adjclose": 111.34500122070312, 
                "date": 1533682800, 
                "close": 111.34500122070312, 
                "open": 111.34700012207031
            }, 
            {
                "high": 111.1780014038086, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-08", 
                "low": 110.70999908447266, 
                "adjclose": 110.89199829101562, 
                "date": 1533769200, 
                "close": 110.89199829101562, 
                "open": 110.90299987792969
            }, 
            {
                "high": 111.12799835205078, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-09", 
                "low": 110.51799774169922, 
                "adjclose": 111.09100341796875, 
                "date": 1533855600, 
                "close": 111.09100341796875, 
                "open": 111.06400299072266
            }
        ], 
        "timeZone": {
            "gmtOffset": 3600
        }, 
        "instrumentType": "CURRENCY"
    }, 
    "EURUSD=X": {
        "eventsData": {}, 
        "firstTradeDate": {
            "date": 1070236800, 
            "formatted_date": "2003-12-01"
        }, 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "prices": [
            {
                "high": 1.169864296913147, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-07-31", 
                "low": 1.166534423828125, 
                "adjclose": 1.168961763381958, 
                "date": 1533078000, 
                "close": 1.168961763381958, 
                "open": 1.168961763381958
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.1669973134994507, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-01", 
                "low": 1.1604158878326416, 
                "adjclose": 1.1665889024734497, 
                "date": 1533164400, 
                "close": 1.1665889024734497, 
                "open": 1.1663848161697388
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.1612001657485962, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-02", 
                "low": 1.1562163829803467, 
                "adjclose": 1.1586008071899414, 
                "date": 1533250800, 
                "close": 1.1586008071899414, 
                "open": 1.1585606336593628
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.1570056676864624, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-05", 
                "low": 1.1530966758728027, 
                "adjclose": 1.1562297344207764, 
                "date": 1533510000, 
                "close": 1.1562297344207764, 
                "open": 1.156136155128479
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.1609008312225342, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-06", 
                "low": 1.1552013158798218, 
                "adjclose": 1.1558021306991577, 
                "date": 1533596400, 
                "close": 1.1558021306991577, 
                "open": 1.155748724937439
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.1629259586334229, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-07", 
                "low": 1.1574609279632568, 
                "adjclose": 1.1602946519851685, 
                "date": 1533682800, 
                "close": 1.1602946519851685, 
                "open": 1.1603351831436157
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.1621150970458984, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-08", 
                "low": 1.156176209449768, 
                "adjclose": 1.1610760688781738, 
                "date": 1533769200, 
                "close": 1.1610760688781738, 
                "open": 1.1610087156295776
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.1539349555969238, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-09", 
                "low": 1.1396141052246094, 
                "adjclose": 1.1523923873901367, 
                "date": 1533855600, 
                "close": 1.1523923873901367, 
                "open": 1.1528706550598145
            }
        ], 
        "timeZone": {
            "gmtOffset": 3600
        }, 
        "instrumentType": "CURRENCY"
    }, 
    "GBPUSD=X": {
        "eventsData": {}, 
        "firstTradeDate": {
            "date": 1070236800, 
            "formatted_date": "2003-12-01"
        }, 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "prices": [
            {
                "high": 1.314578652381897, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-07-31", 
                "low": 1.3097577095031738, 
                "adjclose": 1.3121638298034668, 
                "date": 1533078000, 
                "close": 1.3121638298034668, 
                "open": 1.3118367195129395
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.3128528594970703, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-01", 
                "low": 1.3018969297409058, 
                "adjclose": 1.3126115798950195, 
                "date": 1533164400, 
                "close": 1.3126115798950195, 
                "open": 1.3125253915786743
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.3043080568313599, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-02", 
                "low": 1.2976226806640625, 
                "adjclose": 1.3018121719360352, 
                "date": 1533250800, 
                "close": 1.3018121719360352, 
                "open": 1.301574945449829
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.3007283210754395, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-05", 
                "low": 1.292073130607605, 
                "adjclose": 1.3003562688827515, 
                "date": 1533510000, 
                "close": 1.3003562688827515, 
                "open": 1.300153374671936
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.2973533868789673, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-06", 
                "low": 1.2938284873962402, 
                "adjclose": 1.2944984436035156, 
                "date": 1533596400, 
                "close": 1.2944984436035156, 
                "open": 1.294247031211853
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.2961763143539429, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-07", 
                "low": 1.2855453491210938, 
                "adjclose": 1.2946659326553345, 
                "date": 1533682800, 
                "close": 1.2946659326553345, 
                "open": 1.2946659326553345
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.2911388874053955, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-08", 
                "low": 1.2843565940856934, 
                "adjclose": 1.2881617546081543, 
                "date": 1533769200, 
                "close": 1.2881617546081543, 
                "open": 1.2879958152770996
            }, 
            {
                "high": 1.283861756324768, 
                "volume": 0, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-09", 
                "low": 1.2726045846939087, 
                "adjclose": 1.2828407287597656, 
                "date": 1533855600, 
                "close": 1.2828407287597656, 
                "open": 1.2830052375793457
            }
        ], 
        "timeZone": {
            "gmtOffset": 3600
        }, 
        "instrumentType": "CURRENCY"
    }
}
```

From here you can easily save this JSON data to a file if needed.